# Display php function with smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm beginer in smarty My php function is:

```
   public function list_special() {
        Session::set('was_in_special', 'true');
        if (isset($_GET['showall']) && $_GET['showall'] == 'yes') {
            TPL::$s->assign('products', $this->proc->getSpecialProducts('true'));
        } else {
            TPL::$s->assign('products', $this->proc->getSpecialProducts());
        }
        TPL::$s->assign('title', 'Specialus katalogas - norėdami papildyti specialiųjų kainų sąraša, susisiekite su savo vadybininku.');
        //TPL::$s->assign('products', $this->proc->getSpecialProducts());
        TPL::$s->assign("pages_num", $this->proc->get_special_products_pages());
        TPL::$s->assign("parameters", Request::$params[1] . "/" . Request::$params[2] . "/");
        echo TPL::$s->fetch('catalog.products.html');
    }
```

I want call this function in one page , I try use `{products}` but this nothing display for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should register the object in before display, then call method in template like this:

`{object->method p1='xx' p2='xx'}`

look here.
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/advanced.features.tpl